# Why does ln from Python subprocess fail while it succeeds from normal command line?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, exit-code, ln

As the title says:

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output(['ln', '~/other_folder/src/models/sc_models.py', './src/models/sc_models.py'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['ln', '~/other_folder/src/models/sc_models.py', './src/models/sc_models.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1
>>> exit()
$ ln ~/other_folder/src/models/sc_models.py ./src/models/sc_models.py
$
```

How can this be? How can it succeed from the command line, but fail from the Python subprocess call?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: Try adding `shell=True` to your check_output command

Comment: Don't combine `shell=True` with a list of arguments, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.

```
import os

os.path.expanduser('~/other_folder/src/models/sc_models.py')

In [2]: os.path.expanduser("~")
Out[2]: '/home/padraic'
```

Python is looking for a directory named `~` in your cwd which obviously fails. When you run the code from bash the `~` is expanded, unless you were to use `shell=True` where the command would be passed to the shell and the shell would expand the tilde then you would need to use `os.path.expanduser` or pass the whole path i.e /home/user/other_folder...... I would stick to using shell=False with`os.path.expanduser("~")`.

Comment: Note: the code in the question won't work even if you were to add `shell=True` because only the first list item is executed as a shell command, the rest is interpreted as the shell's arguments on POSIX. In other words: don't use a list argument and `shell=True` together, pass a string instead or (better) don't use `shell=True`: as you've shown it is enough to call `os.path.expanduser('~/...')` here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, why does `check_call(["ls","~/"],shell=True)` work then?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `sh -c 'cmd arg1'` (correct) and `sh -c 'cmd' arg1` (wrong)? For example, see http://bugs.python.org/issue7839